# Save detected rectangular area in OpenCV as a separate image

Tags: opencv

I apply the "squares.c" program overlaps the detected rectangle over the original image. Could someone please suggest how I can save the detected rectangles as a separate images?

I believe there should be a standard function for this in the OpenCV Library, but I am quite new to OpenCV and am still not able to figure that out.

Comment: Checkout below SOF question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132314/how-to-extract-face-from-an-image/9132728#9132728 It is good only if the rectangle is not a rotated one.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#image-roi) is an example for the same in python cv2.